# How to check message delivery in Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is the code that I have used and messages are sucessfully being sent to my device. But **i wanted to check the delivery status** of a message.

How could i do that?
Couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Also, sending a notification from the firebase console shows the delivery status, any way to accesss that?

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import messaging

# import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials

cred = credentials.Certificate("###.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
registration_token = '###'

message = messaging.Message(
    data={
        'disaster': 'earthquake',
        'time': '2:45',
    },
    token=registration_token,
)
response = messaging.send(message)
```

Comment: May I see the output of `print(response)` or `print(response.val())`.

Comment: One more possible thing to do is to implement [Delivery Receipts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#ccs)